# Is there a way to make jQuery Sortable handle nesting?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to write a UI to allow the manipulation of a hierarchical set of data.

The hierarchy contains 'container' and 'component' elements.  A container can contain components and other containers.

I'd like to be able to:

- re-order components/containers within their parent container
- drag components/containers from one parent container to another

jQuery's Sortable Widget very nearly gives me what I need.  I am able to re-order components within a container and drag components from one container to another.

However, when I try to drop a container element, it vanishes.

I've had a look through the API documentation, but can't find anything to help me.

Is it possible to configure jQuery Sortable to do what I need?

Here's the code, it's also on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbxWt/2/) (try dragging the pink div)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .component, .container, .new-component
        {
            font-family: Sans-Serif;
            line-height: 30px;
            min-height: 30px;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #333;
        }
        .container
        {
            background-color: #eee;
        }
        .container > .container
        {
            background-color: #fcc;
        }
        .component
        {
            background-color: #aaa;
        }
        .new-component
        {
            background-color: #ccd;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".container").sortable({
                placeholder: "new-component",
                connectWith: ".container"
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="component">Component 1</div>
        <div class="component">Component 2</div>
        <div class="component">Component 3</div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="component">Component 4</div>
            <div class="component">Component 5</div>
            <div class="component">Component 6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[I've found that removing the { connectWith: ".container" } option allows me to re-order the component/container siblings, but I lose the ability to move components between containers.]

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on the nesting level you want to achieve.

If, a single level is enough then this will do the trick. If you need the ability to nest element deeper then there will be no easy fix.

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $(".container").sortable({
        placeholder: "new-component",
        //connectWith: ".container"
    });
    $(".container div").sortable({
        connectWith: ".container"
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks rusln.  Sadly, I need to nest to an arbitrary depth.

Comment: hmm, it's late here, but this might help you in the right direction : http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/javascript-design-patterns-composite/

Comment: oh, and if all fails, this might help : http://dbushell.com/2012/06/17/nestable-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Thanks again.  Reading the latter made me realise that using DIVs was jsut bad.  Using ul/li has resolved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was needlessly fighting a losing battle using div elements to represent my **list** of data.

Converting it all to ul and li elements did the trick.

Working code below and on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esa7w/):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>jQuery UI Sortable</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        ul 
        {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        ul, li 
        {
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #333;
            min-height: 20px;
        }
        ul 
        {
            background-color: #ccd;
        }
        li
        {
            background-color: #eef;
        }
        li.new
        {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("ul").sortable({
                placeholder: "new",
                connectWith: "ul"
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><span>Component 1</span></li>
        <li><span>Component 2</span>
            <ul>
                <li><span>Component 4</span></li>
                <li><span>Component 5</span></li>
                <li><span>Component 6</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Component 3</span></li>
        <li>
            <span>Component 4</span>
            <ul>
                <li><span>Component 4</span></li>
                <li><span>Component 5</span></li>
                <li><span>Component 6</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```